# Can not call exec(mysql < quicktest.sql)

Tags: php, mysql

I can not get the following line of PHP code to execute on a WAMP install:

```
exec("mysql < quicktest.sql --user=root --password=password");
```

- The actual sql file is very simple and works fine from PhpMyAdmin
- I can run mysql < quicktest... etc from the command line and it works fine
- I can exec() other commands from php no problems, e.g. exec("dir");
- I am calling exec("mysql < ...") from PHP elsewhere on this machine (though via PHPunit)
- Have tried replacing double quotes with quotes
- Have tried escaping the directory separator
- Tried relocating quicktest.sql to same location as script itself
- Tried relocating quicktest.sql to root of htdocs
- Tried assigning the output to a variable and it came up blank (but the mysql command line doesn't return anything anyhow?)
- Tried passing an array as a second parameter to the exec statement to capture any errors, but again came up blank

Any ideas?  Much appreciated!

Comment: You included everything except what happens when you run this command :) blank screen? Also, error reporting on?

Comment: Good point John.  I have error reporting on and see nothing in the logs.  No output is generated on the screen.  If I echo before and after the statement, both echos will appear...

Comment: Why do you want to use the external mysql command for this? Why not use PHP's built-in database functions (such as PDO) to execute the queries in qucktest.sql?

Comment: If you can include code around this line as well as the sql being executed, it may help figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I see wrong is that  `--user=root --password=password` should be before the `<`

Still issues?

Try using the full path to quicktest.sql instead of just the file name.  My guess is that you are not using the correct directory despite your best efforts.

You can run `pwd` in exec to see what path it is being run from.

Another potential issue is permissions.  Run the php script under `sudo` to see if that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  I tried putting --user and --password ahead of the pipe but no change.  I ran dir (not PWD, since I'm on windows), and this shows the current directory is the one with both the php and sql scripts in.  I don't think it's windows permissions.  I can run other commands with exec(), so can't see why mysql would be any different.  (Also, am executing mysql from php elsewhere, via phpunit).

Comment: Did you try adding the full path to the script? Maybe start the script with a simple `select "test";` to see if it is getting reached correctly?  Windows can still have permissions issues - but it seems unlikely in your scenario.  Can you run this script/scenario via phpunit as you've done with others?

Answer (score 1):

Exact same thing happened to my colleague. Apache doesnt know where 'mysql' is located.
Resolved it by adding the mysql path to Window's system variables.

For WinXP

1. right click your computer
2. click 'Properties'
3. click the 'Advanced' tab
4. down the bottom click 'Environment Variables'
5. in the 'System variables' section, find the variable 'Path'
6. click edit and add your MySQL directory

   - for WAMP C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin
   - for XAMPP C:\path\to\xampp\mysql
   - (if you have installed MySQL on your own, your path may be different)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `shell_exec` instead of `exec`. The `<` pipe is a feature provided by your shell, so you need to execute your command from the shell.

Comment: Thanks Sander, but this didn't make any difference... :(

Comment: You could also use proc_open and simply write the contents of quicktest.sql to mysql's STDIN yourself.